FlutterBloc - post event from other event - app hangs on bloc dispose (endless loop?)
My blocs are created and disposed automatically with EventDetailsPage like this:
void _showEventDetails(BuildContext context, String eventId) {
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => DetailsBloc(
              localRepository: context.read<LocalRepository>(),
              mcityRepository: context.read<McityRepository>(),
              parameterDefinitions: context.read<DataBloc>().state.parameterDefinitions,
              parameterDictionaries: context.read<DataBloc>().state.parameterDictionaries,
              userId: context.read<AppBloc>().state.currentUser?.id ?? '',
              appLocalizations: AppLocalizations.of(context),
          )
            ..add(GetEventDetailsEvent(id: eventId)),
        ),
        BlocProvider.value(value: context.read<DataBloc>()),
      ],
      child: const EventDetailsPage(),
    ),
  ),
);

}
So, in this case EventDetailsPage context receives 2 blocs - already existing DataBloc instance and new DetailsBloc instance. DetailsBloc should be auto destroyed after EventDetailsPage is popped from the stack and it works.
DetailsBloc includes some event and it's intended to load some data from repository (webservice network call) and after data loaded, emit state changes to notify gui, this way:
FutureOr<void> _onGetEventDetails(GetEventDetailsEvent event, Emitter<DetailsState> emit) async {

emit(state.copyWith(isLoading: true);
final data = await mcityRepository.loadSomeData();
emit(state.copyWith(isLoading: false, newData: data);

}

It works fine. Even if network call from repository takes some time, when closing EventDetailsPage while network call is in progress, the bloc will be disposed and everything is fine.
But what happens after adding new event from GetEventDetailsEvent like this:
FutureOr<void> _onGetEventDetails(GetEventDetailsEvent event, Emitter<DetailsState> emit) async {

emit(state.copyWith(isLoading: true);
final data = await mcityRepository.loadSomeData();
emit(state.copyWith(isLoading: false, newData: data);

add(GetAdditionalInfoEvent());

}

GetAdditionalInfoEvent is similar to GetEventDetailsEvent. I contains network calls from repository and emit to notify state changes to gui.
But if  add(GetAdditionalInfoEvent()); is present, bloc disposal causes endless loop and app hangs, not reacting to any input (no exception thrown though) in case when bloc is to be disposed before 2 above events finished.
Why? Should I avoid adding new event from other event? In this case, it's not possible to be sure bloc won't be destroyed before all futures finished. From other side, I don't want DetailsBloc exists when EventDetailsPage does not exist.
So, what went wrong here?
